# object_id of current client is is empty

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to execute the code as defined in this file:

https://github.com/Vizzuality/marxan-cloud/blob/staging/infrastructure/kubernetes/modules/key_vault/main.tf

However, when I try to get the object_id (data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id) I see that the value is empty. So, I cannot set the access policy further down.

Now looking at other people's posts regarding the empty object_id, it says that that is due to a change in Azure CLI.

Given this, how does one set the access policy in a key vault for the current client?

Comment: Do you run the terraform code using VM in azure with a Managed System Identity(MSI) or from your local computer?

Comment: From my Windows PC and the state is saved remotely (if that matters). @AndriyBilous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with an older version of the AzureRM provider - Upgrading the version to v3.9.0 fixed the issue. Note that terraform will lock the provider version at init, but you can force an upgrade with the command:

```
  terraform init -upgrade
```

Also you may have version restrictions on providers in your terraform code. You can validate this with the command:

```
   terraform providers
```

You can read more about provider resquirements [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements)

Comment: This worked for me.  Went from v2.75 to v3.11